# How to assign a function on a range of a UILabel text in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UILabel that shown genres of a movie, now I want make the genres clickable to send user to a page of that genre movies.

I have something like this genres = "drama , action , funny" how can have a specific tap on each word

(I just have one UILable that shown genres of the movie that separated by "," how can i have tap on each genre ?)

Comment: What is stopping you from using a button?

Comment: because I don't know count of the genres...

Answer (score 0):

you can use tap gesture recognizer for this. For example

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //suppose I've a label called genereTitleLabel
    let genereTitleLabel = UILabel()
    genereTitleLabel.text = "name of genere"
    genereTitleLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   self.view.addSubView(genereTitleLabel)



    let tapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.genereTapped(_:)))
    tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    genereTitleLabel.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
}

func genereTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //send user to genere moview view
}
```

Comment: I just have one UILable that shown genres of the movie that separated by "," how can i have tap on each genre ?

Comment: you can simply use the `UITapGestureRecognizer` to make the label clickable, and when the genereTapped method is called send user to genere view. Updated the answer

Comment: I have something like this 
genres = "drama , action , funny" 
how can have a specific tap on each word

Comment: It can be done by calculating the position of the click inside UIlabel. But too much overhead, Why don't you try using buttons inside some container UIView. That will be easy and saves you lots of coding

Answer (score 0):

Using a `UIButton` provides this functionality and it will be easier than using a UILabel